# Внедрение ссылки в сообщение telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Не могу добавить ссылку в слово. Когда пользователь пишет в чат команду"!VK" ответ должен быть кликабельным словом содержащим ссылку на профиль вк. (это бот для телеграмма, я использую библиотеку Aiogram)
Код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['VK'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('<a href="ссылка">VK</a>')
```

Ответа бота ответ бота на команду /VK выглядит следующим образом:

```
<a href="ссылка">VK</a>
```

Как это исправить, чтоб ответом было VK с интегрированной в нем ссылкой на профиль?

Answer (score 3):

В `aiogram` есть готовый инструмент для формирования ссылок.

#### Если вы пользуетесь HTML-разметкой:

```py
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hlink

text = hlink('VK', 'https://vk.com')
```

#### Если вы пользуетесь Markdown-разметкой

```py
from aiogram.utils.markdown import link

text = link('VK', 'https://vk.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте разметку `HTML`

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['VK'])
async def process_start_command(message: Message):
    await message.reply('<a href="https://vk.com/id41732290">VK</a>',parse_mode="HTML")
```

Answer (score 1):

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options

Вот ссылка на документацию, там все примеры указаны, как можно редактировать текст и ссылки, соответственно при условии, что будет стоять атрибут parse_mode='...'

```
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '<b>Введи ID товара: </b>', parse_mode='HTML')
```