# Telebot, добовление ссылки в текст Telegarm bot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот, форматирование

> Написал код и хочу добавить в слово: Привет, добавить ссылку

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id ,'[Привіт](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/#description), я чат-бот ', reply_markup=markup,parse_mode='HTML')
```

> На reply_markup=markup не обращайте внимание у меня там кнопки

Answer (score 1):

Вот похожий вопрос. Судя по первому ответу, может помочь
[Внедрение ссылки в сообщение telegram bot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206919/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-telegram-bot)

```
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hlink

hello_with_url = hlink('Привіт', 'https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/#description')
bot.send_message(message.chat.id ,f'{hello_with_url}, я чат-бот ', reply_markup=markup,parse_mode='HTML')
```